Cppcheck does not detect some use-after-free errors?
free.c
#include <stdlib.h>
    
int main() {
    int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)); 
    free(ptr);
    *ptr = 0;
}

Running Cppcheck correctly finds the "use-after-free"-error for *ptr = 0;
cppcheck --enable=all free.c

Checking free.c ...
free.c:6:6: error: Dereferencing 'ptr' after it is deallocated / released [deallocuse]
    *ptr = 0;

However, it fails to detect any errors for ptr[0] = 0;
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)); 
    free(ptr);
    ptr[0] = 0;
}

Is that considered a bug or limitation in Cppcheck?
